# Why does a custom attribute appear both in IL and Metadata?

Tags: .net, metadata, cil, il

There are two attributes like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class Test1Attribute : Attribute
{ }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class Test2Attribute : Attribute
{ }
```

They are pretty simple, don't do anything.

And there is a method that is decorated with those two attributes:

```
public void Hello([Test1]string arg, [Test2] string arg2) { }
```

Now if I compile the code and decompile it with IL Dasm, I'll see the IL code of method "Hello" is like this:

```
.method public hidebysig instance void Hello(int32 arg, int32 arg2) cil managed
{
    .param [1]
    .custom instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test1Attribute::.ctor()
    .param [2]
    .custom instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test2Attribute::.ctor()
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: ret 
}
```

We can see the Test1Attribute and Test2Attribute are both in the IL code.
And its Metadata is like this:

```
MethodName: Hello (06000005)
    Flags     : [Public] [HideBySig] [ReuseSlot]  (00000086)
    RVA       : 0x0000206b
    ImplFlags : [IL] [Managed]  (00000000)
    CallCnvntn: [DEFAULT]
    hasThis 
    ReturnType: Void
    2 Arguments
        Argument #1:  String
        Argument #2:  String
    2 Parameters
        (1) ParamToken : (08000002) Name : arg flags: [none] (00000000)
        CustomAttribute #1 (0c000010)
        -------------------------------------------------------
            CustomAttribute Type: 06000001
            CustomAttributeName: ConsoleApplication1.Test1Attribute :: instance void .ctor()
            Length: 4
            Value : 01 00 00 00                                      >                <
            ctor args: ()

        (2) ParamToken : (08000003) Name : arg2 flags: [none] (00000000)
        CustomAttribute #1 (0c000012)
        -------------------------------------------------------
            CustomAttribute Type: 06000002
            CustomAttributeName: ConsoleApplication1.Test2Attribute :: instance void .ctor()
            Length: 4
            Value : 01 00 00 00                                      >                <
            ctor args: ()
```

Again, both the attributes are also there in the Metadata.

So I am curious about:

1. Why do they appear both in IL and Metadata?
2. What does

   .param [1]
   .custom instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test1Attribute::.ctor()
   .param [2]
   .custom instance void ConsoleApplication1.Test2Attribute::.ctor()

mean? It does not look like instruction. So what are they? What do they do?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about your first question: do you want to know why they are there at all or why they are in IL **and** in Metadata?

Comment: Oh, what I meant is that they appear twice which seems a little verbose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An attribute is just a class, note that you used the *class* keyword to declare one.  Every class has a constructor, even if you don't write one yourself.  The name for the constructor method is .ctor().  Clearly, with any method you get the IL for the code in the method body.

Parameters of a method have their own metadata.  Used here to describe what attribute is applied.  The .param directive gives the parameter number, the .custom directive gives the associated attribute.  This is annotation in the IL syntax, it doesn't physically exist inside the method IL.

The metadata structure is sophisticated with dozens of tables, a disassembler rewrites it to make it more comprehensive.  [Ecma 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) has everything you need if you want to find out what it really looks like.

Answer (score 4):

Custom Attributes are pieces of data that can be attached to mostly any piece of metadata.  If you want the full details - get the [ECMS 335 Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)  Page 231 has the basics.  Page 242 has information about the CustomAttribute metadata table and the serialization format used to store the attribute data is on page 295 (all page numbers are in the actual pdf file page).

Answers to your questions:

1. Two parter:
   a.  You are looking at 2 views of the metadata above (1. IL with the method (and parameter) metadata and 2. the detailed metadata view - minus the IL)
   b.  ILDasm shows you the parts of the method that are needed to execute.  What you may think is odd is that the method signature does not include the attributes - this is because the method signature is just the parameter types.  Any attributes attached to the parameters are just that attached to the parameters and not the signature ... so ILDasm shows you those too - but below the signature.
2. Those are the deserialized and connected metadata of the attributes stored and attached to the parameters.  In your case it is just a call to a default constructor, but in a more complicated case you would have a call to an constructor and data parameters that were also stored in the serialized bits.